# EEEPC UNMOUNTABLE_BOOT_VOLUME

Tags: windows-7, bsod

I have a problem with an Asus EEEPC

When I try to start the PC it shows the BSOD screen with the error UNMOUNTABLE_BOOT_VOLUME.
I have tried to start Windows 7 from USB but after the screen 'Windows is loading files' the PC shows a black screen with the mouse pointer only.
With this problem I'm not able to restore Windows.

Can anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: Test and/or replace you boot volume (hard drive).

Comment: how can i test it?

Comment: There are many utilities out there, some free, some not, some proprietary. Here is a place to start: http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/282651-32-best-diagnostic-testing-utility

Answer (score 1):

If you are unable to boot from USB, the only way to test the drive would be to remove it, hook it up to an external SATA to USB hard drive reader and attach it to another PC. From there, assuming the drive works enough to be detected, you can use programs like Seagate SeaTools or built in windows utilities such as ChkDsk to check the integrity of the disc.